# RDCOMClient read email from a non-Outlook file path

Tags: r, vba, outlook, rdcomclient

I have a number of emails saved outside my Outlook directory, eg. at some file path `"C:\\Users\\foo\\bar.msg"`.

I would like to read these emails into R using `library(RDCOMClient)`; following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573699/how-to-retrieve-outlook-inbox-emails-using-r-rdcomclient) question I have been able to read emails into R from my Outlook folder structure. However given the volume of emails it is not possible to import them into Outlook to read from there.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383290/how-do-i-open-an-outlook-msg-file-from-my-harddrive-that-is-not-in-outlook) question suggests that within VBA  you can use [OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb176433%28v%3Doffice.12%29) to read emails from an external folder, however I haven't been able to translate this into something that works in R. My attempt is:

```
library(RDCOMClient)

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace <- OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

message_path <- "C:\\Users\\foo\\bar.msg"
message <- OutApp$OpenSharedItem("message_path")
```

Comment: Based on the article you linked to it looks like you should open a shared item via a referenced namespace object. Since I do not have Outlook installed have u tried `msg <- outlookNameSpace$OpenSharedItem(..)` yet

Comment: Hi - thanks, yes as per my answer below I spotted that this was the solution. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out there was a wrong object reference in my example above: I reference `OutApp` rather than `outlookNamespace`, when calling CreateItemFromTemplate

Maintaining the question as this might save somebody else the search and interpolating the VBA solution into R.

Working solution:

```
library(RDCOMClient)

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

message_path <- "C:\\Users\\foo\\bar.msg"      
message <- outlookNameSpace$OpenSharedItem(message_path)
```

Comment: Is it correct that you need to pass the string `"message_path"`, and not the value of the variable `message_path` (i.e., the string `"C:\Users\foo\bar.msg"`)?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to use `RDCOMClient` at all for this. hrbrmstr has a package on his github called [msgxtractr](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/msgxtractr) which contains a function `read_msg` that takes as input a file path and returns a list object with all of the details of the message.

To install the package from github, use

```
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("hrbrmstr/msgxtractr")
# Alternate GitLab Repo:
# remotes::install_gitlab("hrbrmstr/msgxtractr")
```

Once the package is installed, you could use:

```r
msgxtractr::read_msg("C:\\Users\\foo\\bar.msg")
```

It's probably worth benchmarking the `RDCOMClient` solution against `msgxtractr`. I suspect that `RDCOMClient` will be a bit slower and probably less stable (since it's communicating between applications).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using msgxtractr as my first approach, but due to limitations imposed by my system admin privileges its not a feasible solution for me, so stuck with RDCOMClient. Agree that this is useful info for people who don't have such restrictions.

Comment: If the issue is that `https://raw.github.com/*` is blocked (which I have seen before), you can always go to the repository and download the zip, the unzip the repository and then build the package using Rtools (assuming you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed). If all of github is blocked, then you could also try the [gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/msgxtractr)

Comment: Hi - it's `rtools.exe` that is the problem, I can't install that.This has caused me problems before as well with trying to install `stan`.

Answer (score 1):

We can also extract the attached files using the following approach :

```
 library(RDCOMClient)
 destination_dir <- "C:\\Users"
 path_msg <- "C:\\Users\\foo\\bar.msg"
 OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
 outlookNameSpace <- OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")
 message <- outlookNameSpace$OpenSharedItem(path_msg)
 nb_Attached_Files <- message$Attachments()$Count()
 list_Attached_Files <- list()
 
 for(i in 1 : nb_Attached_Files)
 {
   print(i)  
   attachment_file <- paste0(destination_dir, .Platform$file.sep, message$Attachments(i)$Filename())
   list_Attached_Files[[i]] <- attachment_file
   message$Attachments(i)$SaveAsFile(attachment_file)
}
```

To extract the subject and the body, we can use the following approach :

```
text_Subject <- message$Subject()
text_Body <- message$Body()
```