# Read from Outllok mailmessages stored on Local Drive

Tags: c#, .net, mailmessage, typecast-operator

I have some MailMessage Objects Copied to Local Directory Lets Say "C:\Users\admin\Documents\MailSamples".
This address has Outlook MailMessages copied manually from Inbox.
What I want to do is programmatically iterate through these MailMessages and fetch data from body of each email.
But I don't have any idea how to type cast path of the mail message to MailMessage Object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open an outlook .msg file from my harddrive that is NOT in outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383290/how-do-i-open-an-outlook-msg-file-from-my-harddrive-that-is-not-in-outlook)

Comment: Hello @niton, Could you please give me C# reference for the same. Sorry to not mention that in question itself

Comment: If the VBA tag is incorrect please remove it.